# How to stop scrolling of Panel scrollbar when textBox is selected

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, textbox, scrollbar

I have a panel called Panel1 that contains many textBoxes .(around 12 textBoxes)

When I click on a textBox (one of the last textBoxes) the Panel's scrollbar position change to another position.(It scrolls automatically and focus changes).

how can i prevent this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not getting your exact problem. I tried to do same as you did, but getting focus on same textBox where i clicked my mouse.

Set some properties of panel
Like:
autoscroll=false;
autoResize=true;

Comment: My panel properties are autoscroll=false  and autoresize=true stil i am not geting it...

Comment: can u be clear once. I did not faced your problem when I tried.

Comment: actually..the textboxes are created dynamically ..i have not used static method.... thanx anyways

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem .

You can use TableLayoutPanel" instead of "Panel" to avoid scrollbar change its position.